# "Type Error: semver is not a constructor" when running new Meteor project?

Tags: meteor

I was following the "simple-todos" tutorial provided by Meteor but when I came to running the "meteor" command within my newly created project on my Desktop using the "meteor create simple-todos" command in the terminal, it comes up with; Type Error: semver is not a constructor.

I have tried re-installing meteor completing and it comes up with the same error, as well as creating the project within my User directory and not in my desktop.

I cannot move forward with the tutorial as it instructs you to visit localhost:3000, but when I go there, it says cannot load page or similar.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The simpl todos for blaze is outdated, me and Harry are working on a new updated version and publish it soon.

Comment: By the way did you run `meteor npm install`?

Comment: It'll be greatly appreciated if you could link me when you have published the updated version. Also, I did try meteor npm install but it came up with the same type error.